# Why do I get an "variable 'std::packaged_task<int> task' has initializer but incomplete type" error

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the below code which gives the error mentioned in the title.  It is a cut down version of the sample available here:

[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task)

```
#include <thread>
#include <future>

int main()
{
    std::packaged_task<int()> task([] {return 1;});
    return 0;
}
```

However, thought that being as I was specifying the type of the package task as int() as specified in another answer here then it would be correctly resolved but it is not.

Can anyone spot what I have done wrong?

Comment: What compiler and version? It compiles without errors on gcc4.8.1

Comment: Compilable with gcc 4.7 and clang 3.1...

Comment: Doesn't compile with MINGW g++ (GCC) 4.6.1

Comment: Thanks guys, I have installed the latest gcc and it compiles properly.  If you make that an answer I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
g++ -E x.cpp > output.txt
```

It will run the preprocessor so you can see what the compiler is getting.

If I run it from cygwin, only the predeclaration of `std::packaged_task` is present in the output, but not the definition. The `future` file contains the following preprocessor condition:

```
#if defined(_GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS) && defined(_GLIBCXX_USE_C99_STDINT_TR1) \
  && defined(_GLIBCXX_ATOMIC_BUILTINS_4)
```

and in my cygwin installation, the macro `_GLIBCXX_HAS_GTHREADS` is not defined, so everything inside the `#if` is removed. Perhaps the same happens to you.